# NGUI avoid line-break in UIInput

Tags: unity-game-engine, line-breaks, ngui

Is there any way to avoid users to input line-breaks in UIInputs?

Do not want the user to be able to write line-breaks in username inputs, for example.

I searched for multiline attribute but it seems it only exists in UILabel objects.

Tried "validation:Username" but this option does not allow to write characters like "-", which is a valid username character of my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> You can similarly limit your input field to a single line by setting the **Max Lines** property to 1 on the **UILabel**.

http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6752.0

Comment: Yes, I found out that is the best solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to check the UIInput.cs file to know how to ignore newlines, and I found this:

```
case KeyCode.KeypadEnter:
            {
                ev.Use();

                bool newLine = (onReturnKey == OnReturnKey.NewLine) ||
                    (onReturnKey == OnReturnKey.Default &&
                    label.multiLine && !ctrl &&
                    label.overflowMethod != UILabel.Overflow.ClampContent &&
                    validation == Validation.None);

                if (newLine)
                {
                    //Insert("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    UICamera.currentScheme = UICamera.ControlScheme.Controller;
                    UICamera.currentKey = ev.keyCode;
                    Submit();
                    UICamera.currentKey = KeyCode.None;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

So in order to avoid newlines, you need to do:

```
UILabelObject.multiLine = false;

UIInputObject.onReturnKey = UIInput.OnReturnKey.Default;
```

Doing that, bool newLine becomes false and performs Submit();